# $.whenall with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a function for returning a feed which is retrieved by an AJAX-Call and now want to do something after a few of these asynchron requests have been done.

`doit()` is the function I call at first.

I am sorry for not providing a url, but it is an internal server.

Here is my code:

```
   function grabFollowedCommunityPageFeed(page, cCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "blabla.com&page=" + page,
                    method: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/atom+xml"
                }).always(function(xhr, ignore, thrownMessage) {
                    var totalResults = 0;
                    if ((200 === thrownMessage.status) && (xhr)) {
                        totalResults = parseInt($(xhr).find("totalResults").first().text()) || -1;
                    }
                    if (cCallback && $.isFunction(cCallback)) {
                        cCallback({feed: xhr, resultCount: totalResults});
                    }
                });
            }

            function grabFollowedCommunitiesFeeds(pagecount) {
                var i = 1,
                    deferredArr = [];
                for (i = 1; i < pagecount; i += 1) {
                    grabFollowedCommunityPageFeed(i, function callback(resultObj) {
                        deferredArr[i] = new $.Deferred();
                        deferredArr[i].resolve(resultObj);
                    });
                }
                return deferredArr;
            }


            function doit() {
                var allCommunityFeedObjects = [],
                    allCommunityFeedObjectsCount = 0,
                    deferredObj = [];
                (function initialReadFollowedCommunityFeedPages() {
                    grabFollowedCommunityPageFeed(1, function(requestObj) {
                        allCommunityFeedObjectsCount = requestObj.resultCount;
                        var tEntries = $(requestObj.communityFeed).find("entry"),
                            el$;
                        $.each(tEntries, function(ignore, el) {
                            el$ = $(el);
                            if (!($.inArray(el$, allCommunityFeedObjects) !== -1)) {
                                allCommunityFeedObjects.push(el$);
                            }
                        });

                        deferredObj = grabFollowedCommunitiesFeeds(allCommunityFeedObjectsCount) || [];
                        $.whenAll.apply($, deferredObj).always(function(allCommunityFeeds) {
                            var k = allCommunityFeeds;
                            // union k with allCommunityFeedObjects
                        });
                    });
                })();

            }
```

This line seems to be fine as well and I have checked it:

```
deferredArr[i].resolve(resultObj);
```

The problem is that allCommunityFeeds parameter is undefined in

```
  $.whenAll.apply($, deferredObj).always(function(allCommunityFeeds)
```

and that means there is something wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: There is no `whenAll` function in jQuery. Did you mean `$.when`?

Comment: @Bergi I believe an extension of jquery $.when is used here. (https://gist.github.com/fearphage/4341799)

Comment: If this (https://gist.github.com/fearphage/4341799) extension is used, then it can use only done() or fail(). It cannot use always(). Please confirm the source of this extension. Also, try with done() or fail(), instead of always().

Comment: @VigneshVaidyanathan you are right. I am sorry, I did not mention that this is an extension for jQuery. whenAll can be called with .always, I have seen it in an example but cannot find it any more.